# How to retrieve sequences from a Fasta file by gene ID

Tags: linux, bioinformatics, fasta

I know this question has been asked a hundred times but I've been at it all day and I can't seem to make this work.
I have a fasta file that looks like this
...

```
>BGI_novel_T016697 Solyc03g033550.3.1
CTGACGTATACAATTAAGCCGCGAAAAATCTACTTTTTTTTTAATAGATATGAATTTCTTTTGTTTCGTATAATGAAGTATTTGTTCCAACAATGTTTAATTATTAGGCATTTGGAATGTGATGGGGCAACTAACAAAGAAGCCAATATCAACATCAATTAACAAACATATGATATAATTCTAGTGAAGTGAAAGCCAAGATATGAAACTCTCCACCCACACTATCTTAAATGATCTTTTTTAAAACATTCTAATTAGGTGATAACTAAAAGCAATAATTCTACCAATTTTGAAACAAACAATATGGTCCC
>BGI_novel_T016313 Solyc03g025570.2.1
TTCAAGTGTTAGTTTCACATCATCACGTTTGGACCTACGTTTCTATATTAGAACATATTCTAACTGATCTCTAGCTGTTATTCATGGGATTGTAAGAAATTTGTATCCCTCTCCGGATTTTACTTTGATCGCCACAAAATGAACATATGCTTTCAATTTTCTATGATGAAAAATCAGCCTCTCTCAATATTGGGTTTAAA
>BGI_novel_T018109 Solyc03g080075.1.1
GCAAGGGAAAGAAGTATTACTAGAGGAGATTTTCCCAACAGTTTTCATTTACACACATGGGTTAAGTATTCATAAATAAAAGAGAAAAATCTGTTTATAAGTTGGAGAGTAGTATAAATACAGGAGATTTTCCCAACAGTTTTCATTTATACACATGGGTTAAGTATTCTTAAATAGAAAATCGGAAGTATTATAAATTCTCACTCAAAGAAACCACGTTTGCTCATTTTCGTTATTCCCTTAAAAACATGGGAAGATGAAAGAAAAAAACTAACACATAAAAAGATTGTGAGTTTACTTATTCATGGAGAATTCCCCATTTAAGTTGACAATATTTTTCTATGGTCTTGAACGGCCAGAAAAGTTAATATCCACAACTATTTTCCACTCAATAAGTGTTCCGATACCGTTGAACTTTTTAATATTTTGCACGCCCTTCGTGAAATGTTTTACTCCGTTACTGTCGCGATAATGATGTTTAAAAT
>BGI_novel_T016817 BGI_novel_G001220
GCCCAAGTCATAGGTAGTGCCTGTGCGGGTTGACACTCAACATGTGACCGCCACCACATTTTGGCATTTCCCTGAAACTGATAGGTTACAAACTCAATGCCAAATCATTCCACTATGCCCATTTTATGTAGTAACTCATGACAATCAACCAGAAAATCGTAGGCATCCTCAGATTCAGCACCCTTGAAGACTGGAGGTTTCAATTTCAAGAACTTACTGAAAAATTCATGCTGATCACTTGTCATTATAGGCCCTGTAGTCAAACGAGGAAACGTGCCTATTTCCAATGAGGCATCCATG
>BGI_novel_T016141 Solyc03g007600.3.1
```

and I want to retrieve the sequences that match the gene IDs from a .txt file:

```
Solyc00g256710.2.1
Solyc01g010890.3.1
Solyc01g056990.3.1
Solyc01g060050.2.1
Solyc01g081120.2.1
Solyc01g097740.3.1
Solyc01g098180.3.1
Solyc01g102320.1.1
Solyc01g106420.3.1
Solyc01g111580.3.1
Solyc01g111970.3.1
Solyc02g005530.2.1
Solyc02g031780.1.1
Solyc02g064595.1.1
Solyc02g081920.3.1
Solyc02g084220.3.1
```

Now, I have already tried samtools and FaSomeRecords, but both these methods produce no output. I guess it's because the title also contains transcript IDs (which I can ignore)
Do you guys have any suggestions for me? please let me know if you require additional information.
Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Perl one-liner, `grep` and `seqtk subseq` to extract the desired fasta sequences:

```
# Create test input:

cat > in.fasta <<EOF
>BGI_novel_T016697 Solyc03g033550.3.1
CTGACGTATACAATTAAGCCGCG
>BGI_novel_T016313 Solyc03g025570.2.1
TTCAAGTGTTAGTTTCACATCAT
>BGI_novel_T018109 Solyc03g080075.1.1
GCAAGGGAAAGAAGTATTACTAG
>BGI_novel_T016817 BGI_novel_G001220
GCCCAAGTCATAGGTAGTGCCTG
>BGI_novel_T016141 Solyc03g007600.3.1
ACGTACGTACGTACGTACGTACG
EOF

cat > gene_ids.txt <<EOF
Solyc03g033550.3.1
Solyc03g080075.1.1
Solyc00g256710.2.1
Solyc01g010890.3.1
EOF

# Extract ids and gene ids into a tsv file:
perl -lne '@f = /^>(\S+)\s+(\S+)/ and print join "\t", @f;' in.fasta > ids_gene_ids.tsv

# Select ids that correspond to the desired gene ids:
grep -f gene_ids.txt ids_gene_ids.tsv | cut -f1 > ids.selected.txt

# Extract fasta sequence that correspond to desired gene ids:
seqtk subseq in.fasta ids.selected.txt > out.fasta                

cat out.fasta
```

Output:

```
>BGI_novel_T016697 Solyc03g033550.3.1
CTGACGTATACAATTAAGCCGCG
>BGI_novel_T018109 Solyc03g080075.1.1
GCAAGGGAAAGAAGTATTACTAG
```

Note that `seqtk` can be installed, for example, using `conda`.

Answer (score 1):

It has been a while for me but the `defline`
(the first line in a fasta record that begins with `>`)
needs to be in particular format to be indexed for
sequence retrieval.

many years (decades) ago I would construct deflines like

```
>gi|123|lcl|xyz ...
```

so sequences could be retrieved with 'xyz'  where 'lcl' was a builtin blast "local" namespace to go along with the default indexed ones.

here you go:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTA_format

coerce your defines to a supported index-able format
re-index then enjoy your very rapid sequence retrieval.

this won't help much if your sequence database is small
and not worth the indexing effort.

In those cases I would just used a `fasta_grep` perl script I had found online somewhere ...

it might have been this one.

http://web.mit.edu/meme_v4.11.4/share/doc/fasta-grep.html

Answer (score 1):

And a small `awk` alternative:

With the `fasta` file looking like this:

```
$ cat fasta 
>BGI_novel_T016697 Solyc03g033550.3.1
CTGACGTATACAATTAAGCCGCGAAAAATCTACTTTTTTTTTAATAGATATGAATTTCTTTTGTTTCGTATAATGAAGTATTTGTTCCAACAATGTTTAATTATTAGGCATTTGGAATGTGATGGGGCAACTAACAAAGAAGCCAATATCAACATCAATTAACAAACATATGATATAATTCTAGTGAAGTGAAAGCCAAGATATGAAACTCTCCACCCACACTATCTTAAATGATCTTTTTTAAAACATTCTAATTAGGTGATAACTAAAAGCAATAATTCTACCAATTTTGAAACAAACAATATGGTCCC
>BGI_novel_T016313 Solyc03g025570.2.1
TTCAAGTGTTAGTTTCACATCATCACGTTTGGACCTACGTTTCTATATTAGAACATATTCTAACTGATCTCTAGCTGTTATTCATGGGATTGTAAGAAATTTGTATCCCTCTCCGGATTTTACTTTGATCGCCACAAAATGAACATATGCTTTCAATTTTCTATGATGAAAAATCAGCCTCTCTCAATATTGGGTTTAAA
>BGI_novel_T018109 Solyc03g080075.1.1
GCAAGGGAAAGAAGTATTACTAGAGGAGATTTTCCCAACAGTTTTCATTTACACACATGGGTTAAGTATTCATAAATAAAAGAGAAAAATCTGTTTATAAGTTGGAGAGTAGTATAAATACAGGAGATTTTCCCAACAGTTTTCATTTATACACATGGGTTAAGTATTCTTAAATAGAAAATCGGAAGTATTATAAATTCTCACTCAAAGAAACCACGTTTGCTCATTTTCGTTATTCCCTTAAAAACATGGGAAGATGAAAGAAAAAAACTAACACATAAAAAGATTGTGAGTTTACTTATTCATGGAGAATTCCCCATTTAAGTTGACAATATTTTTCTATGGTCTTGAACGGCCAGAAAAGTTAATATCCACAACTATTTTCCACTCAATAAGTGTTCCGATACCGTTGAACTTTTTAATATTTTGCACGCCCTTCGTGAAATGTTTTACTCCGTTACTGTCGCGATAATGATGTTTAAAAT
>BGI_novel_T016817 BGI_novel_G001220
GCCCAAGTCATAGGTAGTGCCTGTGCGGGTTGACACTCAACATGTGACCGCCACCACATTTTGGCATTTCCCTGAAACTGATAGGTTACAAACTCAATGCCAAATCATTCCACTATGCCCATTTTATGTAGTAACTCATGACAATCAACCAGAAAATCGTAGGCATCCTCAGATTCAGCACCCTTGAAGACTGGAGGTTTCAATTTCAAGAACTTACTGAAAAATTCATGCTGATCACTTGTCATTATAGGCCCTGTAGTCAAACGAGGAAACGTGCCTATTTCCAATGAGGCATCCATG
>BGI_novel_T016141 Solyc03g007600.3.1
GCCCAAGTCATAGGTAGTGCCTGTGCGGGTTGACACTCAACATGTGACCGCCACCACATTTTGGCATTTCCCTGAAACTGATAGGTTACAAACTCAATGCCAAATCATTCCACTATGCCCATTTTATGTAGTAACTCATGACAATCAACCAGAAAATCGTAGGCATCCTCAGATTCAGCACCCTTGAAGACTGGAGGTTTCAATTTCAAGAACTTACTGAAAAATTCATGCTGATCACTTGTCATTATAGGCCCTGTAGTCAAACGAGGAAACGTGCCTATTTCCAATGAGGCATCCATG
```

The ID file `a.txt` like that:

```
$ cat a.txt 
Solyc00g256710.2.1
Solyc01g010890.3.1
Solyc01g056990.3.1
Solyc01g060050.2.1
Solyc01g081120.2.1
Solyc01g097740.3.1
Solyc01g098180.3.1
Solyc01g102320.1.1
Solyc01g106420.3.1
Solyc01g111580.3.1
Solyc01g111970.3.1
Solyc02g005530.2.1
Solyc02g031780.1.1
Solyc02g064595.1.1
Solyc02g081920.3.1
Solyc02g084220.3.1
Solyc03g080075.1.1
Solyc03g007600.3.1
```

We can do this:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0]++} FNR!=NR{if($NF in a){print $0; getline; print}}' a.txt fasta 
>BGI_novel_T018109 Solyc03g080075.1.1
GCAAGGGAAAGAAGTATTACTAGAGGAGATTTTCCCAACAGTTTTCATTTACACACATGGGTTAAGTATTCATAAATAAAAGAGAAAAATCTGTTTATAAGTTGGAGAGTAGTATAAATACAGGAGATTTTCCCAACAGTTTTCATTTATACACATGGGTTAAGTATTCTTAAATAGAAAATCGGAAGTATTATAAATTCTCACTCAAAGAAACCACGTTTGCTCATTTTCGTTATTCCCTTAAAAACATGGGAAGATGAAAGAAAAAAACTAACACATAAAAAGATTGTGAGTTTACTTATTCATGGAGAATTCCCCATTTAAGTTGACAATATTTTTCTATGGTCTTGAACGGCCAGAAAAGTTAATATCCACAACTATTTTCCACTCAATAAGTGTTCCGATACCGTTGAACTTTTTAATATTTTGCACGCCCTTCGTGAAATGTTTTACTCCGTTACTGTCGCGATAATGATGTTTAAAAT
>BGI_novel_T016141 Solyc03g007600.3.1
GCCCAAGTCATAGGTAGTGCCTGTGCGGGTTGACACTCAACATGTGACCGCCACCACATTTTGGCATTTCCCTGAAACTGATAGGTTACAAACTCAATGCCAAATCATTCCACTATGCCCATTTTATGTAGTAACTCATGACAATCAACCAGAAAATCGTAGGCATCCTCAGATTCAGCACCCTTGAAGACTGGAGGTTTCAATTTCAAGAACTTACTGAAAAATTCATGCTGATCACTTGTCATTATAGGCCCTGTAGTCAAACGAGGAAACGTGCCTATTTCCAATGAGGCATCCAT
```

Explanation of the `awk`-stanza:
`FNR==NR{a[$0]++}`

While we operate on the first file, the IDs, we add each ID to an array;

`FNR!=NR{if($NF in a){print $0; getline; print}}'`

When we reach the fast file we take the last field `$NF` of each line and check it it exists in the array; if it does we print the line and the line following it.

Answer (score 1):

Since a FASTA construct is a two line pair consisting of a defline (e.g. `>BGI_novel_T016697 Solyc03g033550.3.1`) followed by a line that contains the sequence, you can probably use the `--after-context` argument to `grep` to return the matched line followed by the next line.  None of the gene IDs in your example are in the example FASTA file you gave, but if I add a matching gene ID to that file for testing, you can see how it works.

Gene lookup file:

```
$ cat lookup.txt
cat lookup.txt
Solyc00g256710.2.1
Solyc01g010890.3.1
Solyc01g056990.3.1
Solyc01g060050.2.1
Solyc01g081120.2.1
Solyc01g097740.3.1
Solyc01g098180.3.1
Solyc01g102320.1.1
Solyc01g106420.3.1
Solyc01g111580.3.1
Solyc01g111970.3.1
Solyc02g005530.2.1
Solyc02g031780.1.1
Solyc02g064595.1.1
Solyc02g081920.3.1
Solyc02g084220.3.1
Solyc03g080075.1.1
```

Sequence FASTA file:

```
$ cat seqs.fa
>BGI_novel_T016697 Solyc03g033550.3.1
CTGACGTATACAATTAAGCCGCGAAAAATCTACTTTTTTTTTAATAGATATGAATTTCTTTTGTTTCGTATAATGAAGTATTTGTTCCAACAATGTTTAATTATTAGGCATTTGGAATGTGATGGGGCAACTAACAAAGAAGCCAATATCAACATCAATTAACAAACATATGATATAATTCTAGTGAAGTGAAAGCCAAGATATGAAACTCTCCACCCACACTATCTTAAATGATCTTTTTTAAAACATTCTAATTAGGTGATAACTAAAAGCAATAATTCTACCAATTTTGAAACAAACAATATGGTCCC
>BGI_novel_T016313 Solyc03g025570.2.1
TTCAAGTGTTAGTTTCACATCATCACGTTTGGACCTACGTTTCTATATTAGAACATATTCTAACTGATCTCTAGCTGTTATTCATGGGATTGTAAGAAATTTGTATCCCTCTCCGGATTTTACTTTGATCGCCACAAAATGAACATATGCTTTCAATTTTCTATGATGAAAAATCAGCCTCTCTCAATATTGGGTTTAAA
>BGI_novel_T018109 Solyc03g080075.1.1
GCAAGGGAAAGAAGTATTACTAGAGGAGATTTTCCCAACAGTTTTCATTTACACACATGGGTTAAGTATTCATAAATAAAAGAGAAAAATCTGTTTATAAGTTGGAGAGTAGTATAAATACAGGAGATTTTCCCAACAGTTTTCATTTATACACATGGGTTAAGTATTCTTAAATAGAAAATCGGAAGTATTATAAATTCTCACTCAAAGAAACCACGTTTGCTCATTTTCGTTATTCCCTTAAAAACATGGGAAGATGAAAGAAAAAAACTAACACATAAAAAGATTGTGAGTTTACTTATTCATGGAGAATTCCCCATTTAAGTTGACAATATTTTTCTATGGTCTTGAACGGCCAGAAAAGTTAATATCCACAACTATTTTCCACTCAATAAGTGTTCCGATACCGTTGAACTTTTTAATATTTTGCACGCCCTTCGTGAAATGTTTTACTCCGTTACTGTCGCGATAATGATGTTTAAAAT
>BGI_novel_T016817 BGI_novel_G001220
GCCCAAGTCATAGGTAGTGCCTGTGCGGGTTGACACTCAACATGTGACCGCCACCACATTTTGGCATTTCCCTGAAACTGATAGGTTACAAACTCAATGCCAAATCATTCCACTATGCCCATTTTATGTAGTAACTCATGACAATCAACCAGAAAATCGTAGGCATCCTCAGATTCAGCACCCTTGAAGACTGGAGGTTTCAATTTCAAGAACTTACTGAAAAATTCATGCTGATCACTTGTCATTATAGGCCCTGTAGTCAAACGAGGAAACGTGCCTATTTCCAATGAGGCATCCATG
```

Grep command with `-w` for whole word matching (in case you might get a partial result), `-f` to use a file of terms / patters to search, and `-A1` to return the next line after a match:

```
$ grep -w -f lookup.txt -A1 seqs.fa
>BGI_novel_T018109 Solyc03g080075.1.1
GCAAGGGAAAGAAGTATTACTAGAGGAGATTTTCCCAACAGTTTTCATTTACACACATGGGTTAAGTATTCATAAATAAAAGAGAAAAATCTGTTTATAAGTTGGAGAGTAGTATAAATACAGGAGATTTTCCCAACAGTTTTCATTTATACACATGGGTTAAGTATTCTTAAATAGAAAATCGGAAGTATTATAAATTCTCACTCAAAGAAACCACGTTTGCTCATTTTCGTTATTCCCTTAAAAACATGGGAAGATGAAAGAAAAAAACTAACACATAAAAAGATTGTGAGTTTACTTATTCATGGAGAATTCCCCATTTAAGTTGACAATATTTTTCTATGGTCTTGAACGGCCAGAAAAGTTAATATCCACAACTATTTTCCACTCAATAAGTGTTCCGATACCGTTGAACTTTTTAATATTTTGCACGCCCTTCGTGAAATGTTTTACTCCGTTACTGTCGCGATAATGATGTTTAAAAT
```

Unless you have some complex pattern matching and / or some post processing that needs to be done, I think a simple grep should get you there a little more simply.